# How to connect Oculus Link on Win10 Parallels VM

Tags: windows, parallels-desktop

How to connect Oculus Link on Win10 Parallels VM?

Tried to connect Oculus Quest to the MacBook Pro 16" with Parallels Desktop - Win 10 VM on it. Connected official OculusLink-cable USB-C to headset and to mac. But Win sees Oculus Quest only as a storage device, - Oculus app doesn't see the headset. (Also tried to click "Connect oculus link" from settings in headset - no effect, Oculus App and Headset doesn't see each other)

[image: Win on Parallels Desktop see Oculus Quest only as storage device]

Made little research, seems like others also can't get it working via straight-forward way.

- https://forum.parallels.com/threads/has-anybody-gotten-oculus-link-working-in-their-win10-parallels-vm.348916/

Does anybody got it working? Is there some existing workarounds?

Comment: Is the **GPU** reported by **Windows** one which is compatible with the device?